# How to get the value from state in Yew Rust

Tags: rust, yew

I have a state in Yew that looks like this:

```
let is_flipped: UseStateHandle<bool> = use_state(|| false);
```

As you can see, its type is `UseStateHandle<bool>`.

I want to extract its boolean value so I can toggle the state:

```
let onclick: Callback<MouseEvent> = {
    let is_flipped = is_flipped.clone();
    Callback::from(move |_| match is_flipped {
        true => is_flipped.set(false), // <- type error
        false => is_flipped.set(true), // <- type error
    })
};
```

But I am getting this error:

```
^^^^^ expected struct `UseStateHandle`, found `bool`
```

How can I obtain the boolean value contained in the state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`UseStateHandle` implements `Deref`](https://docs.rs/yew/0.20.0/src/yew/functional/hooks/use_state.rs.html#127-133). You just need to dereference it:

```rust
let onclick: Callback<MouseEvent> = {
    let is_flipped = is_flipped.clone();
    Callback::from(move |_| match *is_flipped {
        true => is_flipped.set(false),
        false => is_flipped.set(true),
    })
};
```